# How to display different Cells in a Column depending on the type?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a an interface of type `IItemParameter` and few instantiations of it with a generic.
The definitions are as follows:

```
public interface IItemParameter
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public struct ItemParameter<T> : IItemParameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private T _Default { get; set; }
    public T Default { get => _Default; set => _Default = value; }
}
```

I instantiate `ItemParameter<int>` and `ItemParameter<string>` and `ItemParameter<bool>`.

I would like to display a collection of these types in a DataGridView with two columns:
`Name` and `Value`, where `Name` is the Name property of the Parameter and `Value` is displayed as a TextBoxCell (`string`/`int`) or CheckBoxCell(`bool`)

I use a `BindingList<IItemParameter>` to store the parameters like so:

```
//Transform ObjectParameters into ItemParameters for display
foreach (var param in parameters)
{
    if (param is ObjectParameter<bool>)
    {
        ObjectParameter<bool> boolParam = (ObjectParameter<bool>)param;
        _bindingList.Add(new ItemParameter<bool> { Name = param.Name, Value = boolParam.Default });
    }
    if (param is ObjectParameter<string>)
    {
        ObjectParameter<string> stringParam = (ObjectParameter<string>)param;
        _bindingList.Add(new ItemParameter<string> { Name = param.Name, Value = stringParam.Default });
    }
    if (param is ObjectParameter<int>)
    {
        ObjectParameter<int> intParam = (ObjectParameter<int>)param;
        _bindingList.Add(new ItemParameter<int> { Name = param.Name, Value = intParam.Default });
    }
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingList;
```

The DataGridView displays only the first column (Name) though.

How would I display the second column with a cell depending on the type of the parameter?

Comment: How would a DataGridView Cell be able to show a `string`, an `int` and a CheckBox for a `bool` value in the same Column? You could redefine your Interface, adding a `string Default {get; }` property and convert `_Default` to string in the getter of that Property. The `BindingList<IItemParameter>` now could work and you don't need to switch between Types, just add a new `ItemParameter<Whatever>` without checking the Type. Of course the values shown in the DGV are all read-only strings, unless you provide a converter. `Converter<T>` already has a generic definition for the delegate.

Comment: Of course, if you want to change the value of `_Default` in the UI, you'd  also need a custom DataGridViewCell that *draws* a display value for the Property and provides means to edit it (with a custom `EditingControl`). Unless you could accept strings values as `"True"` and `"False"` for the `bool` Type properties. If instead these values are just used for presentation (read-only), there's nothing else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I believe you have 2 problems.  The 1st is that you are defining the binding list like this:

```
BindingList<IItemParameter>
```

If you look at that interface it only has 1 property.  Name!

```
public interface IItemParameter
{
   string Name { get; set; }
}
```

...So, that's what your list is displaying!

The 2nd problem is that, this still would not work because the values for that column would be of different types (`bool`, `string`, `int`).  You might need to make your T variable `private` and then have a `public` variable which converts your `T` to a string.

But, if the data in this grid is just for display purposes, what I would be tempted to do is just create a helper class like this:

```
public class DisplayData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

then setup the binding list to be of type `DisplayData` and in your loop do something like this:

```
var _bindingList = new BindingList<DisplayData>()

foreach (var param in parameters)
{
    if (param is ObjectParameter<bool>)
    {
        ObjectParameter<bool> boolParam = (ObjectParameter<bool>)param;
        _bindingList.Add(new DisplayData { Name = param.Name, Value = boolParam.Default });
    }
    if (param is ObjectParameter<string>)
    {
        ObjectParameter<string> stringParam = (ObjectParameter<string>)param;
        _bindingList.Add(new DisplayData { Name = param.Name, Value = stringParam.Default });
    }
    if (param is ObjectParameter<int>)
    {
        ObjectParameter<int> intParam = (ObjectParameter<int>)param;
        _bindingList.Add(new DisplayData { Name = param.Name, Value = intParam.Default });
    }
}
```